How to replace environment field with command field in docker compose file for memgraph/memgraph-platform
how to replace environment field with command field in docker compose file for memgraph/memgraph-platform
I'm trying to modify a Docker Compose file to remove the environment field and replace it with the command field.
To use Blueprint41, I need to set this flag:
--storage-enable-schema-metadata=true

However, the documentation has no entry for this Docker image:
memgraph/memgraph-platform:2.xx.x-memgraph2.xx.x-lab2.xx.x

Here is my setup:
command: ["--log-level=TRACE", "--storage-enable-schema-metadata=true"]

When I run the Docker Compose file, the container doesn't start and prints the following error:
Error: option --log-level not recognized


Starting with version 2.15, Memgraph Platform transitioned to a multi-container application and the platform image is no longer being updated.
If you still want to use the platform image (up to version 2.14), there's a bit of a difference whenlisting the environment flags. You will need to use the .env file where you can list your flags under the MEMGRAPH
environment variable.
I would suggest switching to multi-container app and using separate images for Memgraph and lab just so you can keep up with updates in new versions of Memgraph.
